# Java HotSpot: lazy loading of classes is not working

Tags: java, class, lazy-loading

```
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

Java lazy loading of classes not working. e.g.,

```
public class Foo() {

   public Bar createBar() {
        return new Bar(false);  <----------raised exception
   }
}

public class Bar {
   public Bar(boolean createHello) {
      if (createHello) {
          Hello hello = new Hello();  // Hello: not in runtime classpath
          ...
      }

   }

}
```

The class Hello is optional for the application, so it may not be in runtime classpath.

When running the code, the JVM throws

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello
```

At the line indicated before the constructor `new Bar(false)` is executed.

For lazy loading of classes, Hello.class should never be loaded.

Does Java HotSpot JVM use lazy loading of classes?  lazy loading is JLS standard or implementation-specific?

How to workaround this issue? Reflection is not the right solution for us.

Comment: Why do you *expect* `Hello` to be loaded "lazily" (i.e., not when `Bar` is loaded)?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the place where the exception happens? I'm assuming that the import of the `Hello` class fails when creating loading the `Bar` class.

Comment: From debugging, the exception thrown when stepping into new Bar(false). I expect the exception only when new Hello() is invoked.

Comment: Are you sure that the code compiles and you aren't trying some old version of the Foo.class? createBar() method is declared as void, however you are returning Bar object from it.

Comment: Typo, corrected. Thanks.